# Can I use a plot function as a figure layout template and populate the subplots by using other custom plot functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to define some plotting functions to automate my workflow. I have worked out how to flexibly automate my layout to have a main top plot and any number of subplots below as needed (see fig.1). But I have other defined plotting functions of richer content I would like to use to populate the layout. Is it possible to use a layout function and take other custom plot functions as arguments to populate the subplots?

[image]

Here is my function for figure 1:

```
def plot(*args, **kwargs):
    ''' Automates plotting of top plot with multiple plots possible (via *args), and any # of bottom 
        subplots with a single plot for each (via **kwargs).
        '''
    plt.rc('font', size=6)
    plt.style.use('ggplot')

    if kwargs:
        subs = len(kwargs.keys())
        hr_params = [max(3, subs+1)]
        hr_params.extend([1] * subs)
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(subs+1, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(8, max(6, subs+1)), 
                                 gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': hr_params})

        # Main plot
        for item in args:
                axes[0].plot(item, label=item.name) #, color=next(colors))  # make a list named colors if want specific colors
        axes[0].legend(loc='best')

        # Sub plots
        ax_dict ={}
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            ax_dict[i] = ax
        for i, item in enumerate(kwargs.values(), 1):
            ax_dict[i].plot(item, label=item.name)
            ax_dict[i].legend(loc='best')

        fig.tight_layout()

    else:
        plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
        for item in args:
            plt.plot(item, label=item.name) #, color=next(colors))  # make a list named colors if want specific colors
        plt.legend(loc='best')

    return None
```

So, in figure 2 for example, I was hoping to be able to call the above function using other `custom_plot()` functions as inputs like this:

```
kwarg_dict = {'sub1': custom_plot2(), 'sub2': custom_plot2(), 'sub3': custom_plot2()}
plot(*custom_plot1(), **kwarg_dict)
```

Comment: Instead of creating the figure inside your function, create it outside and pass the required axes to the function. This will allow you to reuse your function anywhere you need it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest But I am trying to set this up as a module that I can call and pass arguments which will then determine how the figure is output (ie: how many subplots based on how many time-series are given by **kwargs). Make sense?

Comment: Yes, but as said, you will first need to set up a figure with as many axes as needed, then populate the axes.

Comment: Your approach looks fine, so what are you having trouble doing?  If you wanted nested subplots (i.e. you want axs[2] to have three subplots inside it) you can nest subplots:  See the second and third example in:  https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#use-with-gridspec